# How can I prevent Exim from sending bounces when it receives permanent errors from a specific server?

Tags: email, spam, exim

I've got an Exim server that I'm trying to evaluate a commercial spam filtering product with.  The relevant setup:

1. Exim acts as edge mail server.
2. Mail received by the mail server is relayed to the spam filter.
3. If the message's IP is on a blocklist, the spam filter rejects the message.
4. Exim receives a permanent delivery failure and sends a bounce to the spam's "from" address, resulting in backscatter.

I would like to disable permanent delivery failure reports in Exim, but only for mail rejected by the spam filter.  How can I do this?

Comment: Why is exim sending a NDR at all? That's not normal. How did you set this up?

Comment: I've updated with what I hope is a better question.  As far as setup, I didn't.  I inherited a horrible complex mess of a config that I'm only allowed to make incremental changes to.

Comment: The problem there is that exim is accepting the message before sending it to the spam filter. Again, what is the configuration?